# Post multiple images Django

Tags: django, database, image, post

So I tried changing my model to upload multiple images. But as you may guess I am not uploading to database. Asking for a clue as to why. Following a tutorial to do it but not seeing what I messed up.

Mote my form has all the fields Im just showing partial info in model and form

**View**

```
def add_seller(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
      sellerform = SellerForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      files = request.FILES.getlist('car_image')
      if sellerform.is_valid():
         seller_form = sellerform.save(commit=False)
         seller_form.save()

         for f in files:
             img =Image(image=f)
             img.save()
             seller_form.image.add(img)
         seller_form.save()
         print(seller_form + "Valid")
      sellers  = VehicleStats.objects.all()
      return render(request, 'index.html', {'sellerform': sellers})
    else:       

        sellerform  = SellerForm()
        print(sellerform )

    return render(request, 'add_seller.html', {'sellerform': sellerform})
```

**Model**

```
class VehicleStats(models.Model):
    car_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    car_image = models.ManyToManyField('Image')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.contact_name



class Image(models.Model):
    car_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images")
```

****Form****

```
class SellerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = VehicleStats
        
        widgets = {
            'model' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'series' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'date_added':forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'type':'date'}),
            'car_image' : forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'multiple': True}),
        }
```

Comment: I see you are calling `seller_form.save()` twice. Once before adding images and once after. Try removing the first instance of `seller_form.save()`

Comment: tried that  no luck